# Displaying Total From Query in Footer of DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a query I am running every time the search button is clicked. Right now I have the total in a label just below data grid on the page. I would like to show the total on the right hand side of the footer.

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:TableCell>
    <asp:DataGrid ID="myGrid" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        BackColor="#E3DFD7"
        BorderColor="black"
        ShowFooter="false"
        CellPadding="3"
        CellSpacing="0"
        Font-Name="Calibri"
        HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
        Font-Size="11pt"
        HeaderStyle-Font-Size="13pt"
        HeaderStyle-BackColor="#286090"
        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white"
        EnableViewState="false" />
</asp:TableCell>
```

I know I have the footer set to false right now, because I am not using it, but what would be a good way to set a variable holding a total to the footer of my data grid?

Answer (score 0):

create a template for footer in your page like this:

```
 <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"/>
 </FooterTemplate>
```

now you can assign a value for the label `lblTotal` for example in RowDataBound event of grid view:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
     {
      Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
      lbl.Text = yourcalculatedValue.ToString();
     } 
}
```